# C (on win32): How to fix value of daylight greater than 1?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin, mingw

The following sample for [`daylight`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/daylight) test_daytime.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (void)
{
    char *tzval;

    tzval = "TZ=";
    putenv(tzval);
    tzset();
    printf ("tz: \"%40s\" - daylight: %d\n", tzval, daylight);

    tzval = "TZ=EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2";
    putenv(tzval);
    tzset();
    printf ("tz: \"%40s\" - daylight: %d\n", tzval, daylight);

    tzval = "TZ=AEDT";
    putenv(tzval);
    tzset();
    printf ("tz: \"%40s\" - daylight: %d\n", tzval, daylight);

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
$gcc test_daytime.c -o test_daytime.exe && ./test_daytime.exe
```

produces the following output on Cygwin (`uname`: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW) and MSYS2 (`uname`: MSYS_NT-10.0)

```
tz: "                                     TZ=" - daylight: 0
tz: "          TZ=EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2" - daylight: 1
tz: "                                 TZ=AEDT" - daylight: 0
```

This is the result on MSYS (`uname`: MINGW32_NT-6.2, same machine)

```
tz: "                                     TZ=" - daylight: 1
tz: "          TZ=EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2" - daylight: 69
tz: "                                 TZ=AEDT" - daylight: 84
```

I assume the reason for this is the MSVCRT that is used in MinGW, see [MinGW MSYS, MSVCRT, and the TZ environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765650/mingw-msys-msvcrt-and-the-tz-environment-variable), but isn't a value > 1 not completely wrong (I know that the manpages say "not zero" but are there any systems that don't set the values to a different value than 0/1)?

Any idea how to fix this (without changing the MSYS environment)?

Comment: What's `daylight`? Update: Nvm, found it...

Comment: It doesn't have to be `1`. The valid values are `zero` and `non-zero`. Why would you want to "fix" it if it is not "broken"?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know that the manpages say "not zero" (as I've written in the question) but I don't see that the results are actually correct and wonder if other environments set `daylight` to a different value than 0/1.
It seems that `daylight` for `AEDT` should return 0, shouldn't it?

Comment: Are they actually non zero when they should be zero?

Comment: The link that you yourself gave says that the `daylight` variable is obsolete.

Comment: Also it says "*Note that the variable daylight does not indicate that daylight saving time applies right now. It used to give the number of some algorithm*". So you see the number of "some algorithm".

Comment: @BenVoigt I've actually missed this part :-)
But the question stay the same (even an obsolete variable shouldn't be set *wrong*), don't you think?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It shows (or should show) if there was *ever* a daylight saving time for the timezone in the past or in the future. This is actual the *only* reason to use it nowadays.

Comment: This is probably the authoritative specification: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tzset.html

Comment: [tzset and daylight global variable interpretation in time.h](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33992832/2410359) may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that any *true* (i.e. non-zero) value becomes `1`, the easiest way is to use `!!`:

```
printf ("tz: \"%40s\" - daylight: %d\n", tzval, !!daylight);
```

will print `1` for any non-zero value of daylight (and `0` if the value is zero).
(Hope I got your question correctly)

Comment: Agree, use `!!` - there is nothing to "fix".